# Correct way to share functions between components in React

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple components which all need to do the same thing. (A simple function which maps over their child components and does something to each one). At the moment I am defining this method in each of the components. But I only want to define it once.

I could define it in the top level component and then pass it down as a prop. But that doesn't feel quite right. It is more a library function than a prop. (It seems to me).

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Check out [this link](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750). Or search for "mixins" and "HOC" in google.

Comment: Great question. For a newbie like me this has been a gold mine of information :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you use something like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) then you can have an external file i.e util.js that exports some utility functions.

```
var doSomething = function(num) {
 return num + 1;
}

exports.doSomething = doSomething;
```

Then require it as needed

```
var doSomething = require('./util.js').doSomething;
```

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya That depends, what are you using to manage the front end state of your app?

Comment: I am using react states.

Comment: Why i am getting  'doSomething ' is not defined    no-undef  any idea?

Answer (score 104):

## Utils.js with latest Javascript ES6 syntax

Create the `Utils.js` file like this with multiple functions, etc

```js
const someCommonValues = ['common', 'values'];
    
export const doSomethingWithInput = (theInput) => {
   //Do something with the input
   return theInput;
};
    
export const justAnAlert = () => {
   alert('hello');
};
```

Then in your components that you want to use the util functions, import the specific functions that are needed. You don't have to import everything

```js
import {doSomethingWithInput, justAnAlert} from './path/to/Utils.js'
```

And then use these functions within the component like this:

```js
justAnAlert();
<p>{doSomethingWithInput('hello')}</p>
```

Comment: What is the `/file` at the end of the import line for?

Comment: @alex It's just an example. Put your relative path to the util.js there

Comment: It's better to remove that `/file`, your example uses `Utils.js` so that's exactly what should be shown there

Comment: is it best to keep it in the `/src` folder or `/components` folder?

Comment: @Embedded_Mugs I would put it in `src/helpers/utils.js`. Also I usually create separate file for similar functions for example `pathHelpers`, `authHelpers`

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to React and you've shown me another way to do it :)

Answer (score 19):

If you want to manipulate state in helper functions follow this:

1. Create a Helpers.js file:

`export function myFunc(){ return this.state.name; //define it according to your needs }`

2. Import helper function in your component file:

   `import {myFunc} from 'path-to/Helpers.js'`
3. In your constructor add that helper function to the class

   `constructor(){ super() this.myFunc = myFunc.bind(this) }`
4. In your render function use it:

   `render(){

   {this.myFunc()}
   }`

Comment: Beautiful! I'm new to React and this is another little nugget of information that's helping me along :)

Comment: The constructor was the vital thing for me :) Editing to indicate that it requires super() beforehand.

Answer (score 12):

Here are some examples on how you can reuse a function (`FetchUtil.handleError`) in a React component (`App`).

## Solution 1: Using CommonJS module syntax

```
module.exports = {
  handleError: function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
    return response;
  },
};
```

## Solution 2: Using "createClass" (React v16)

**util/FetchUtil.js**

```
const createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

const FetchUtil = createReactClass({
  statics: {
    handleError: function(response) {
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
      return response;
    },
  },
  render() {
  },
});

export default FetchUtil;
```

Note: If you are using React v15.4 (or below) you need to import `createClass` as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
const FetchUtil = React.createClass({});
```

Source: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass

## Component (which reuses FetchUtil)

**components/App.jsx**

```
import Categories from './Categories.jsx';
import FetchUtil from '../utils/FetchUtil';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {categories: []};
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    window
      .fetch('/rest/service/v1/categories')
      .then(FetchUtil.handleError)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(categories => this.setState({...this.state, categories}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container={true} spacing={16}>
        <Grid item={true} xs={12}>
          <Categories categories={this.state.categories} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Solution one is quite good, I used the same thing in ExpressJS

Comment: Thanks for Solution 2! It solved an issue I was having (I'm new to React) where the Utility function wasn't being recognised. I was trying to call it using this.Utility.HandleError(...) rather than simply Utility.HandleError(...) without the "this".

Answer (score 8):

Another solid option other than creating a util file would be to use a higher order component to create a `withComponentMapper()` wrapper. This component would take in a component as a parameter and return it back with the `componentMapper()` function passed down as a prop.

This is considered a good practice in React. [You can find out how to do so in detail here.](https://hackernoon.com/react-reusable-component-state-805163dc355)

Comment: I am curious as to why React discourages component inheritance where the withComponent pattern seems to be similar?

Answer (score 8):

I'll show two styles below, and you'll want to choose depending on how much the components' logic relate to each other.

**Style 1 - Relatively related components** can be *created* with callback references, like this, in `./components/App.js`...

```
<SomeItem
    ref={(instance) => {this.childA = instance}}
/>

<SomeOtherItem
    ref={(instance) => {this.childB = instance}}
/>
```

And then you can *use* shared functions between them like this...

```
this.childA.investigateComponent(this.childB);  // call childA function with childB as arg
this.childB.makeNotesOnComponent(this.childA);  // call childB function with childA as arg
```

**Style 2 - Util-type components** can be *created* like this, in `./utils/time.js`...

```
export const getTimeDifference = function (start, end) {
    // return difference between start and end
}
```

And then they can be *used* like this, in `./components/App.js`...

```
import React from 'react';
import {getTimeDifference} from './utils/time.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    someFunction() {
        console.log(getTimeDifference("19:00:00", "20:00:00"));
    }
}
```

**Which to use?**

If the logic is **relatively-related** (they only get used together in the same app), then you should share states between components.  But if your logic is **distantly-related** (i.e., math util, text-formatting util), then you should make and import util class functions.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a utility function, in that case why not put it in a separate static utility module?

Otherwise if using a transpiler like Babel you can make use of es7's static methods:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static someMethod() { ...
```

Or else if you are using React.createClass you can use the [statics](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#statics) object:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    customMethod: function(foo) {
      return foo === 'bar';
    }
  }
```

However I don't advise those options, it doesn't make sense to include a component for a utility method.

Also you shouldn't be passing a method down through all your components as a prop it will tightly couple them and make refactoring more painful. I advise a plain old utility module.

The other option is to use a mixin to extend the class, but I don't recommend that as you can't do it in es6+ (and I don't see the benefit in this case).

Comment: The information about mixins is useful. In this case I want to conditionally use the function rather than have something happen automatically on a lifecycle event. So. As you say a plain old utility function is the way to go.

Comment: Note: ``React.createClass`` is deprecated since React 15.5.0. create-react-app suggests use of the npm module ``create-react-class`` instead.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing as the OP but I'm a bit confused here. You don't recommend any of the options you list. What **do** you recommend?

Comment: I would simply make a file for the function e.g. `doSomething.js`, or a file with multiple similar "utility" functions e.g. `utils.js` and import those functions where you need to use them

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you use a Mixin for this ?  See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Although they are falling out of favour see https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

Might be useful

Comment: I agree that mixin is a better solution here than just exporting a common function.

Comment: @TaoHuang Some things to consider, 1.Mixins are not future proof and will get used less and less in modern apps, 2.Using an exported function makes your code framework agnostic - you could easily use those function on any other js project. Also please read this post about why NOT to use Mixins --> https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html

Comment: A mixin may access and modify state, while a trait does not, and since the OP is saying they want something to treat as a function library, a mixin would not be the right solution.

Comment: To update this , use higher order functions .  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: First link is dead