# I have a configuration JSON I want to share between React components, what's the best way?

Tags: reactjs, dry, composition

I'm going to be using some configuration data that I want shared between several different React components.  Instead of coding those config data objects into each component I want to be able to DRY it up into one file/json string and share that object between components.

What's the most sane/best way of doing this?

(I was looking at Mixins and noticed that they're being deprecated in React at some point, so wanted to avoid this.
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html
)

What are other possibilities?
Passing an obj into via properties?
Creating a file and importing it?
Other better ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to share functions between components in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888728/correct-way-to-share-functions-between-components-in-react)

Comment: Dan the issue is that it's not 'functions', it's data.  It's config objects that I want to pass around.

Comment: functions and "data" are both just Javascript objects.  The pattern for sharing them amongst React components is going to be the same:  most likely they're going to be passed around as props (mentioned here) or imported from an external file (mentioned in the linked question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep it in state and pass those configuration as default props to every component.

Comment: Yeah I think that's going to be the best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you create a util file and export the functions from there? Then import the relevent functions where needed

Comment: That would be great but it's mainly config DATA.  There's no functions which is why I was confused and it felt weird to make an config data object into an exports.

Comment: You could do a config file and import it as well. Irs pertty common