# How to handle global functions and global variables using webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

```
addMethod.js

function add(){
  // do something
}
```

Let say, I have a function `add` which can be accessed globally. But when I bundled this file with webpack(v4) I am facing an error `add of undefined` when I ran that file in the browser.

So far in my research, I have only come across people recommending that **global functions and methods must be appended to window object**

The problem is in a larger project, how do I handle these kinds of problems?

I know I can use `export or window` keyword.

But I am looking for any webpack plugin that will take care of this, instead of me having to update every file in my project??

**Note: Webpack version - 4 and `ES5`**

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888728/correct-way-to-share-functions-between-components-in-react/32889002#32889002

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to share functions between components in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888728/correct-way-to-share-functions-between-components-in-react)

Comment: Thanks for your response ... Instead of updating every files is any webpack plugin can handle it ? @deowk

Comment: ok if you don't want to import them have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to import these functions in each file, you can add your `global` functions to a file called `globals.js` for example then add the following to your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    ...
    alias: {
      'global': [path_to_global.js] 
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'global': 'global'
    })
  ]  
}
```

Then you can call you functions with `global.yourFunction()` anywhere in your app.

Comment: I got your answer.. Let say, The problem is it's a big project and it has many global variables and global functions..So then i to have check each files and update to `global.functionName`  everywhere right? I guess it's not best way to update each files just becoz of webpack.

Comment: I Guess better have some webpack plugin to resolve these kind of issues Am i right?

Comment: Suppose If i remove the webpack later then i will face an error right ? `global of undefined`

Comment: Yes you'll need to move all your global functions to the same file, if you have global variables you'll need to use `DefinePlugin` to expose them. You are going to have to do some work to get to get the project inline with best practices. OR you can just plonk them all onto the window object and accept the risks that come with that.

Comment: @ManjunathDavanam why would you remove webpack?

Comment: Just I am saying later some other best  tool came  than webpack

Comment: @ManjunathDavanam Then you cannot seriously expect that your whole project will build with this `other best tool` without any changes.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @deowk. I am saying just becoz of webpack we should not touch the code right .. The one thing i felt webpack is not best fit for ES5 am i right?

Comment: If you have global functions in your app my personal opinion is that it's better to prefix these methods with `global` because any developer looking at your code will 
instantly know that he is looking at a global function. In fact if you are going to add these onto the `window` object I would even recommend namespacing them in the same way. (with a more unique name of course)

Comment: Cool, I will think about it  @deowk

Comment: One more clarification. Actually what i did instead of touching every file i just wrote a wrapper file to expose as global variable( link: https://gist.github.com/manjudr/e9494a409e90ff85066a87c3aacad44a) but still i am facing an issue `add of undefined` you have any idea for this?  @deowk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174401/discussion-between-manjunath-davanam-and-deowk).

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to use webpack(4/5) to bundle js together from  tags where code continued under it. I would suggest to actually not use webpack for this case, use uglifyJS/uglifyCSS.

```
npm install uglify-js -g

uglifyjs --compress --mangle --output bundle.js -- js/jquery.js js/silly.js
```