# How to pass function and data from component class to stateless class in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am working with react native and I want to pass function and some data from **Component** class to another **Stateless** class, but I could not make to passing function and data part.

**Here you can see my Component class:**

```
class Classroom extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);



    };

    state = {
        isLightOn: false,
        title : "Turn light on "
    }

   onPress() {
       this.setState({isLightOn: !this.state.isLightOn})
       console.log(this.state.isLightOn)
       this.setState({title:this.state.isLightOn===false ?"Turn light off":"Turn light on"})

   }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.blue}>

                <LightBulb  isLightOn={this.state.isLightOn}> </LightBulb>
                <LightButton onPress={this.onPress} isLightOn={this.state.isLightOn} title={this.state.title} > </LightButton>


            </View>
        );
    }


}
```

Firstly, I want to pass **isLightOn** and **title** datas to my **LightButton** class (which mean to my stateless class). After that, I want to use onPress function inside of my Stateless class, but I cannot use. I am taking that error:

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I also LightButton onPress={this.onPress} remove parenthesis, but still taking error.

**Here is my my Stateless class**

```
const LightButton = ({onPress,isLightOn,title}) => (


        <View style={styles.red}>


            <Button
                title= {title}
                onPress={() => {}

                }
            />
        </View>
)
```

I want to use onPress function and datas inside of the this class.
As a result, How can I pass function and data to that class?

Comment: Can you show how you *were* using `onPress` in `LightButton`? My guess is you were doing it something like `onPress={onPress()}`?

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661103/2430549 "Correct way to share functions between components in React."  There are actually two paradigms (to begin with!). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you need to declare `onPress` using an arrow function or bind it to the component's `this` value within the constructor. Otherwise it wouldn't have access to the correct this value. Other than that, the way you were passing props into components is perfectly fine.

I also merged your two set state calls in `onPress` to one as it's easier.

In LightButton, I set it up like this to pass the onPress function down to the button:

```
const LightButton = ({ onPress, isLightOn, title }) => (
  <div style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
    <Button title={title} onPress={onPress} />
  </div>
);
```

(I set it up using react, but the issues at hand are more of a JS issue than a React/ReactNative one, so the advice should still be valid :) )

```js
const { Component } = React;
const View = 'div';
const Button = (({title,onPress})=><button onClick={onPress}>{title}</button>);

const LightBulb = ({ isLightOn }) => {
  return <div className={'LightBulb' + (isLightOn ? ' on' : '')} />;
};

const LightButton = ({ onPress, isLightOn, title }) => (
  <div style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
    <Button title={title} onPress={onPress} />
  </div>
);
class Classroom extends Component {
  state = {
    isLightOn: false,
    title: 'Turn light on ',
  };

  onPress=()=> {
    console.log(this.state.isLightOn);
    this.setState({
      title:
        this.state.isLightOn === false ? 'Turn light off' : 'Turn light on',
        isLightOn: !this.state.isLightOn
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
        <LightBulb isLightOn={this.state.isLightOn}> </LightBulb>
        <LightButton
          onPress={this.onPress}
          isLightOn={this.state.isLightOn}
          title={this.state.title}
        >Button</LightButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Classroom />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
.LightBulb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
.LightBulb.on {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it like

---

```
const LightButton = ({onPress,isLightOn,title}) => (
  ...
  onPress={onPress}
  ...
```

---

or with an arrow function if you need to pass arg inside

---

```
onPress={()=>onPress(someArg)}
```

---

do notice that you either don't put `()` at all, or twice `() => func()` for not run the function while it is just loads and not clicked.

unrelated directly to your issue but something that you encounter is inside `onPress` by doing like so

---

```
 this.setState({isLightOn: !this.state.isLightOn})
 console.log(this.state.isLightOn)
 this.setState({title:this.state.isLightOn===false ?"Turn light off":"Turn light on"})
```

---

`setState` it is an async call, and therefore second `setState` usage not guaranteed to refer the state as you expect, use `setState({ ... }, () => callback())` or all at one line and accords to prev state

---

```
 this.setState({isLightOn: !this.state.isLightOn, title: !this.state.isLightOn===false ?"Turn light off":"Turn light on"})
```

Comment: I think you're right about the async confusion, but I'm not sure it would solve the max update depth error. My guess is the error is related to the first section of your answer and they were most likely doing `onPress={onPress()}`. Once they clear up that error, the second part of your question will be helpful too.

Answer (score -2):

1. First thing you did wrong is your state instantiating !
   you need to instantiate your state in the `constructor` block like:

```js
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = { counter: 0 };
}
```

2. `onPress()` you use this for your function which is not recommended in react native or any other language , those are dedicated functions and methods of React Native
3. For passing a parameter or calling a function it is better to use these patterns ====>

`onPress={() => urFunction()}` with parenthesis or

`onPress={urFunction}` without parenthesis

Do the modifications I hope it helps <3

Comment: Do you have a reference for the advice against using `onPress` as a function name? I don't think that's right, but if you have a source I'd be happy to be corrected.

Comment: as its dedicated function it cant be used , i was just reasoning and making subject clear.

Comment: as i mentioned it cant be used

Comment: But why can't it? Its just a javascript function name. Its not a reserved class method like `constructor`. Do you have a source?

Comment: there is nothing in docs for mentioning that , but it is better not to use it , because it can cause some conflicts in the mind of developers I don't know