# How to pass functions to different components react

Tags: reactjs

Sorry for the noob question in advance. I have got a button, and I have a function in a different folder which I am trying to execute... I have tried to import the function from  my other folder however it does not seem to be exceuting...How do I call this correctly?

ModalTopBar.js

```
import LineageContent from  '../../ReusableComponents/Lineage/LineageContent'



              <Button text='Get SQL' onClick={LineageContent.onHandle} />
```

LineageContent:

```
  const onHandle = () => {
    console.log('clicked')
  }
```

File path to where I am importing lineage content if it helps:

[image]

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question elsewhere that should be helpful: [Correct way to share functions between components in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661103/2430549)  And if that's not enough, I have another!  [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549)

Answer (score 0):

First of all lets clear that the `Components` in `reactjs` is reusable so you can't simply `import` a `new instance` then use a `nested function` from this `component`

if the `Component` that you want to use a `nested function` is `parent` or even `ancestor` to the current `component` then you should `props` and pass the `function address` throw it
else you should use something like `redux` and save this `function address` in a `store` then use wherever you want ***this is a bad practice to use redux***